# How can I create thousands of images and pixels in the screen at the same time? using Python

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, pygame

For a simulation project, I need to create and manage a huge number of individual pixels and small gifs in a graphics environment under python. 
I tried "graphics.py". But, it crashes after adding around 3000 objects. The error code is not self-explanatory:

"Python has stopped working" Problem signature: Problem Event Name: APPCRASH Application Name: python.exe Application Version: 3.5.1150.1013 Application Timestamp: 576eff6a Fault Module Name: tcl86t.dll

Do you have any idea what is the problem? Even, is "graphics.py" suitable for handling a great number of objects?
Thanks

ADDED: 
Here is a sample of when I instantiate a new object or move it:

...

```
    self.image__ = Image(Point(self.x_, self.y_), 1, 1)

           #shaping image with some pixels
    self.shape_single_cell()                

           #sending image to the screen
    CreatureSingleCell.world_handle__.draw_image(self.image__)
```

...

```
    #moving the image to a new spot in the screen
def action_single_cell_moving(self, dx, dy):
     self.image__.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you're having problems with ?

Comment: Is graphics.py referring to [this](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py)? From a quick glance, it looks like it is based off of tkinter, so I am not sure how fast it will perform. It might also help to know what exactly are you doing in the simulation. Do you intend to interact with these gifs and have a user interface, or is the focus more on simply rendering them?

Comment: Actually, the code is very long and complicated, unsuitable for posting here. In some situations, I create new pixels or images on the screen. And in each time tick, they move a few pixels in a direction based on simulation. Pretty simple, the only challenge is the number of them. When it crashes, it is not clear which part of the code is liable.

Comment: @user2588654 yes, iti is zelle's graphics. The calculations and simulations are perfectly robust and fast. In fact, they have been tested thoroughly without GUI. The GUI is only for presenting real-time output of simulations. I don't receive input from GUI.

Comment: So are you manipulating individual pixels every frame and moving those around, or are you moving sprites/images around? If you are "moving" individual pixels, then perhaps the simulation needs to create a single fullscreen/window texture image that contains the resulting desired pixels. This single "quad" would then be rendered to the screen every frame. If you are manipulating individual sprites, then multiple quads each containing a sprite will be needed instead. It also would help if we had a description of what the simulation did or at least an example of the format of the data it outputs.

Comment: @ user2588654 Thank you for your comment. Please have a look at the code sample that I just added to the question body. In first version, I was working with pixels. But, now there are all images. Most of them very small, in size of one or a few pixels. It is not in "pygame" style. When I want to move one of images in the screen, I just call image.move() function of the library. It works fine(though slow), until 1 or 2 hours of running when the number of images increases a lot. I did not completely get what you said about quad and rendering. It looks like pygame style. Yeah?

Comment: In that case, if you working with on the order of thousands of small images, you might want to consider something like Pyopengl. In OpenGL and 3D graphics, images are rendered as a rectangle made out of two triangles (a "quad"). Pygame and graphics.py (I assume) are not hardware accelerated and thus are performing slowly. Does the number of objects grow over time? For the current simulation without graphics, are you just keeping a list of objects and the dx and dy values by which you move them every frame?

Comment: @user2588654 Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, the objects die and born, and through time the number of them is changing but mainly increasing. Actually, it is a simulation for the theory of evolution. Without graphics, I use a list of objects and their properties including x and y. I have been trying pygame for a few days. But you suggest me to immigrate to PyOpenGL. A hassle starting a new platform!! Again, thank you a lot

Comment: @RezaAmani You can use pygame to create the window for pyopengl, but you are right about starting from scratch. I have written some answers in response to other questions about pyopengl on this site that might help you get started. If you go down that route and look at OpenGL, I would ignore anything that uses immediate mode stuff like glBegin as you will likely run into the same performance bottlenecks quickly. I would suggest googling about vertex buffer objects (VBOs) for rendering. In the meantime I will try to create a basic random motion simulation that you can use to get started.

Comment: @user2588654 Wow! what a great help! thank you very much dear kind unmet friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a final answer yet, but just so you have something to look at for the meantime, I created a simulation where I have 1000 squares which randomly twitch around. Using the simple but slow techniques involving glBegin that I mentioned in my comments, I still get about 60 fps, while at 10000 objects, it drops to 7 fps. No texturing or object birth/death at the moment, but I thought it might be a good start. Is this a reasonable representation of your evolution simulation? Also let me know what performance you get on your computer and if this is sufficiently fast for your simulation purposes or if it needs to switch to more complicated/advanced techniques.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import math
import pygame
import random
import sys
import time

class Creature(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Simulation(object):
    def __init__(self, world_size, num_creatures=1000, max_move=1):#not really max by pythagorean theorem
        self.width, self.height = world_size
        self.max_move = max_move
        self.creatures = self.setup(num_creatures)

    def setup(self, num_creatures):
        creatures = []
        for i in range(num_creatures):
            x = int(random.random()*self.width)
            y = int(random.random()*self.height)
            creature = Creature()
            creature.set_pos(x, y)
            creatures.append(creature)
        return creatures

    def update(self):
        for creature in self.creatures:
            dx = int(round(random.uniform(-self.max_move, self.max_move)))
            dy = int(round(random.uniform(-self.max_move, self.max_move)))
            creature.move(dx, dy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 800
    height = 600
    title = "Random Simulation"
    target_fps = 60
    pygame.init()
    size = (width, height)
    flags = pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.OPENGL
    pygame.display.set_mode(size, flags)
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

    c = Creature()
    sim = Simulation(size)

    prev_time = time.time()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
                pygame.quit()

        sim.update()   
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

        for i in sim.creatures:
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            glVertex(i.x - i.size/2.0, i.y - i.size/2.0)
            glVertex(i.x + i.size/2.0, i.y - i.size/2.0)
            glVertex(i.x + i.size/2.0, i.y + i.size/2.0)
            glVertex(i.x - i.size/2.0, i.y + i.size/2.0)
            glEnd()
        pygame.display.flip()

        curr_time = time.time()
        diff = curr_time - prev_time
        delay = max(1.0/target_fps - diff, 0)
        time.sleep(delay)
        fps = 1.0/(delay + diff)
        prev_time = curr_time
        pygame.display.set_caption("{0}: {1:.2f}".format(title, fps))
```